# Google Drive Icon file. Cant compile Eclipse Android Project

Tags: android, eclipse, google-drive-api

I created Android project and placed it on Google Drive.

But when I tried to compile it I got errors, because Google Drive adds to project folders a file "Icon".

Who knows how to remove this file? Or make Google Drive not to create these files?

OS: Mac OS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't find a setting and deleted these files:

```
find . -d -name '.git' -exec find {} -name 'Icon?' -delete \;
```